# What is the purpose of splitting SLAM odom and EKF odom frames in waypoint_nav?

Tags: slam, navigation, ekf, gmapping, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot somewhat similar to the [clearpath husky](https://github.com/nickcharron/waypoint_nav) . In their gmapping launch file, they have their odom frame set to 'odom_gmapping'. config shown here:

```
<!-- Setting frames -->
<param name="odom_frame" value="odom_gmapping"/>
<param name="base_frame" value="base_link"/>
<param name="map_frame" value="map"/>
```

But in every other instance (costmaps, EKF, etc.) the odom frame is set to 'odom'. What is the point of having two split odom frames like that?

I know that if they used 'odom' in both, then the map-> odom ekf and gmapping would broadcast the same transform, but I am confused how this works

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412276/what-is-the-purpose-of-splitting-slam-odom-and-ekf-odom-frames-in-waypoint_nav?/) by [chased11](https://answers.ros.org/users/115712/chased11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2023-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you are meant to run mapping as a discrete process, and then used that generated map for navigation later on. I don't think they intended for you to run mapping while you are running the nav stack.

In any case, `tf` wouldn't allow them to run at the same time. You cannot have two parents for a given frame in ROS, so if the normal nav is publishing `odom->base_link` and the mapping is publishing `odom_gmapping->base_link`, tf will complain and won't function correctly. The only excaption there is if they are inverting the publication of the `odom_gmapping->base_link` transform and instead publishing the `base_link->odom_gmapping` transform. In that case, they might want to have independent state estimates in two frames.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2023-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1